# Horizontal bouncing in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

For some reason, my UITableView is bouncing horizontally (not scrolling, bouncing). Setting `alwaysBounceHorizontal` to NO doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found an answer .. ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the view hierarchy that its within? UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass so I can imagine it might start doing this if it was within a view that was slightly to small?

Comment: I have actually made the table view smaller than its containing view, and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your UITableView is a subview of a UIScrollView it might start doing this.  Be very careful about this.